# How to turn off hover effect after certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, hover, mousehover

I have a hover effect where when the icon image is hovered over, an larger image appears (for clarity). I want this larger image effect to end after three seconds AND still have the hover ability. If the image is moved off of, then came back to; I want the larger image to load for another three seconds. Every time the image is hovered over, the effect would last three seconds.

I have tried CSS animations, transitions, setTimeout and none of them are working like I need. Any help is appreciated. I have a LOT of code on this project, so I will try to only include the relevant parts. Thanks in advance.

I will have the code added to the question, once i figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Code for building levels for hover image**

```
#PlayerMarker1 {
  position: absolute;
  left:2%;
  top: 2%;
  z-index: 9;
}

#Player1Final{
  position: absolute;
  left:2%;
  top: 2%;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Elements for Image load on hover*/

.playerMarker img{
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  }

.playerMarker:hover{
  background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .playerMarker:hover img{
  border: 1px;
  }
  
  .playerMarker span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;

  padding: 0px;
  left: -1000px;
  /*background-color: black ;*/
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .playerMarker span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  }
  
  .playerMarker:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
  z-index: 50;
  }
```

Code for defining the images.

```
<div id="Player1Test">
    <a id="PlayerMarker1" href="#thumb1"><img src="Player Markers/Morty_Icon.png" width="auto" height="auto"/><span><img src="Player Images/Morty_Token.png" /><br /></span></a>
  </div>
```

This script adds the playerMarker classes to the element I need.

```
  /* Script to add class to player marker ID items */

   function Player1Function() {
   var Player1FinalTest = document.getElementById("PlayerMarker1");
   Player1FinalTest.classList.add("playerMarker");
   Player1FinalTest.id='Player1Final';
   }
```

Comment: you could just add a [css transition delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) for 3s.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. 

Wouldn't that method just delay the hover form starting for 3s? or can I use it to stop the hover effect? This was the first thing I found, but perhaps I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like css animations to pulse the image would work fine. Run the code snippet to try.

```css
img {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

img:hover {
  animation: pulse 2s 1;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.4);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<h4>Hover the mouse over image<h4>
<img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Comment: This is a good start. OP is hiding by using absolute positioning and moving off screen though. Could animate the `left` value just as easily though.

Comment: Close, I'm not moving anything off the screen, but I am hiding the edges of the main background under divs on the side. 

I think this pulse could work, I just need to figure out if it can play nice with the rest of what I have. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @DemonicHedgehog - Unfortunately I posted the answer before you updated the question with code.  So the details were not known then. Yet, I think it is enough to start you in the right direction.

Comment: of course. It's an incredibly convoluted piece of code, written by someone with a veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery basic understanding. I appreciate you even attempting before I had the code up. Thanks dude.

Comment: Thank you Yogi. I am on the right track. I used the pulse animation you suggested and set the 100% scale to 0. At this point, when I hover for three seconds, the image DOES disappear.

 However, it comes back to the same 100% scale and repeats the animation.  is there a way to keep the animation at the finished state UNTIL the mouse leave the image. Then it would run again. Thank for all your help.

Comment: The issue now is that the animation is running all the time in the background. It's not resetting on each hover. I'm sure i screwed something up. but this is the new hurdle. Thanks again.

Comment: This was the solution. Thank you so much. I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Yogi has a good answer using an animation that could be adapted to clearly move your element. I wanted to add an answer manipulating the left and top values using delay.

You are essentially moving a hidden image from off screen onto the screen. Though this feels a bit strange to do, as there may be more clear ways of accomplishing this task, you can immediately move the `left` into view, and delay moving the `top` out of view.

A different delay is needed for the hover and for the base element, so it returns to the original position immediately and is available for reuse, but delays moving away on hover.

This might keep in spirit of your current project.

If you have any questions, please ask

```css
.playerMarker {
  background-color: lightblue;
  --size: 4rem;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
}

.playerMarker span { 
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: -1000px;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  transition: top 0s;
}
  
.playerMarker span img { 
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}
  
.playerMarker:hover span { 
  transition: top 0s 2s;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1000px;
  left: 100px; 
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="playerMarker">
  <span>
    <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" />
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is where i got to before. I could delay the animation, but not stop it. Now your code tests EXACTLY how i need. I just need to figure out why my hover image doesn't end like yours.

Just some context: The 'icon' the user hovers over is draggable. So the 'hover image' follows and traces the icons movements. That's why it 'hides and reappears' the way it does. I have that part working, but the 'hover image' covers other parts of the screen while moving the 'icon'. That's the reason i am trying to have the 'hover image' go away after 2/3s

Comment: Mine doesnt technically end the left moving in, it delays the top moving out. I had to add a delay to `top` on hover, and remove the delay on the "hoverless" css.

Comment: @DemonicHedgehog I strongly suggest using the transform scale and keyframes animation demonstrated by Yogi in your use case, if you want to be dragging an element and want the hover'd element to track your drag.